# Navigating through JSP pages using Dropdown selected values

Tags: jsp, servlets, model-view-controller, netbeans, drop-down-menu

I have a question regarding JSP and Servlet. I am using MVC model in IDE. The JSP page index.jsp is being called when I run the code first. Now my Servlet is my controller. The Jsp page has a dropdown box having two values. The deal is if I select one value suppose option 1 out of two options and submit it. The control should go to Contoller(Servlet). The control gets transferred to Controller but I need to redirect it to a new page which is related to option 1. Here, I mean to say that both the values of dropdown should lead me to two different pages after submitting my index.jsp.

```
 protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {

        String page = request.getParameter("option");



        if(request.getParameter("option").equals("1")){

            request.setAttribute("s1", page);
            RequestDispatcher req = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("BrowseMovie.jsp");
            req.forward(request, response);
        }
        else if(request.getParameter("option").equals("2")){
            request.setAttribute("s2", page);
            RequestDispatcher req = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("AddNew.jsp");
            req.forward(request, response);
        }


    } finally {
        out.close();
    }
}





   <html>
   <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Browse Page</title>
    </head>
    <body color="PINK">
    <form action="Controller" method="post">
    <h1>Welcome to our Movie Store</h1>
    <br>
    <p>Please make your selection below</p>
    <br>
    <select>
        <option value="1" name="option">Browse Movies</option>

        <option value="2" name="option">Add New Movie To Database</option>

        <input type="submit" value="Send" name="Send"/>
    </select>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: You forgot to tell us what your problem is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to navigate to another page as soon as user select a dropdown option, then it's not possible to achieve with only jsp or servlet. You need to add a little bit of javascript code to do this.
in javascript,create a function to get the form element by tagname or id and then submit it. And fire this function through another function which will be triggered as soon as user select a dropdown option.
In this way you can achive the thing you asked :)